# Auto smooth shading problems

Tags: faces

[image]

With auto smooth on, the shading is weird

[image]

without auto smooth , its clean
[image]

Comment: you should show us your topology....

Comment: could you please share your file (the part you show only): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: try to make a mesh with all quads.

Comment: @XY dont be hating on the triangles :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Object Data Properties* panel, under the *Geometry Data* tab, try using the *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.
I am still not sure what it does, but it works for me sometimes.

[image: Clear Custom Split Normals Data option under Geometry Data]

Hope this helps !

Comment: It removes any custom normals data.  The normals for faces are usually calculated from the geometry of the face, so that they just point outwards - but blender is happy to let you overwrite them with normals pointing in arbitrary directions.  Typical sources of this include using the bevel command with Harden Normals, applying a Weighted Normals modifier, painting the normals or really anything that manually or automatically modifies normals!  Clearing it like you suggest resets it to calculated from the face and edge angles.

Comment: Aahaa ... I didn't know here were so many ways to override the normals directions! Thanks a lot for the clarifications... :)